# Word for a statement that embodies its own 'theme'?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

eg, "People over-generalize."  Sort of, 'autological', for sentences.

Comment: Alexander Pope, in a real *tour de force* in his "Essay on Criticism," offers up a whole series of these, in [this section](http://www.poetryfoundation.org/learning/essay/237826?page=6).

Answer (score 0):

Self-fulfilling prophecy, self-generating

- Self-fulfilling prophecy?

Something that causes its own self to be true.

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-fulfilling_prophecy

- Self-generating

Causes its own creation

https://www.google.com.sg/search?q=self-generating&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&hl=en-sg&client=safari

Answer (score -2):

Autology it is.

> [autology](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/autology) (TFD)
>   the study of oneself.

Autology does not necessarily apply to words alone. In fact, it's an adjective in the term 'autological word.'

> *Ulysses* contains all the major ingredients of a **self-begetting narrative;** yet the novel's overriding **autology,** especially as it connects to Stephen's story, has been largely ignored. (emphasis mine)
>   <sup>Margaret McBride, *Ulysses and the Metamorphosis of Stephen Dedalus,* Bucknell, 2001,
>    [GoogleBooks p.30](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=IP0wSd5W9vAC&pg=PA30&lpg=PA30&dq=autology&source=bl&ots=nyvvTQzn22&sig=SImBbkewyWj1-dpRlrTj21egcOA&hl=en&sa=X&ei=9gudVPuXDM2nuQSf5YC4CQ&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=utology&f=false)</sup>

Comment: *[Autological word](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autological_word)* (per Wikipedia) seems to hit reasonably close to the mark here, and OED confirms *autological* as "**Of a word**, esp. an adjective: having or representing the property it denotes" (my emphasis); but the parent form *autology* carries no such sense as is inquired for here, either in TFD or OED, and *autological* appears applicable to single words only, not phrases or lines, which is what OP seems to be asking about.

Comment: @BrianDonovan "autological appears applicable to single words only, not phrases:" because you looked up "autological **word**" -- what else would you expect? Lol.

Comment: My link is to a Wikipedia entry for "autological word," but my quotation is from the OED entry for "autological."